# Backbone JS, navigating different views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, navigation

I'm currently learning Backbone.js (so apologies if this is a silly question) whilst creating a small hangman game.

I've successfully created the game which allows the player to play, get a score and restart the game after winning/losing however my question is in regards to implementing an initial menu screen and navigating to the game or options pages etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this, is it by simply showing the menu, then when the user clicks to play, hiding or clearing the DOM elements of the menu page and initialising the game views which will display the game page? Then, when the user returns to the menu doing the same thing, clearing the game views and showing the menu.

Sorry for my simplistic question and I hope I have explained myself well enough. I have searched around and looked through several tutorials in hope of finding an answer but nothing seems to address the problem I'm facing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backbone.js [router component](http://backbonejs.org/#Router), and assign execution of views on specific urls.
It is probably the most elegant way.

Comment: Thanks, so using the router component would I do what I explained in my initial question and hide/show DOM content depending on the URL, is this normal in backbone apps or would this be considered bad practice?